# Flutter, Dart: The value of the local variable'uint8list' isn't used. Is displayed even though the declared variable is used

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

```
//main.dart
// The declared uint8list turns gray (android studio).
//The value of the local variable 'uint8list' isn't used.
//It is displayed as above. It is considered unused.

                  var uint8list;  //←string color is gray.
                  var file;
                  var bytes;
                  Widget sumb=Container(width:100);

                  try{
                      uint8list = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
                      video: tempurl,
                      thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
                      imageFormat: ImageFormat.WEBP,
                      maxHeight: 200,
                      // specify the height of the thumbnail, let the width auto-scaled to keep the source aspect ratio
                      quality: 75,
                    );
                  }catch(e){

                  }


                  uint8list="";  //←← Described as a trial. Even with this, the declaration part remains gray.
```

I'm trying to create a thumbnail from a video file uploaded to cloud_storage in firebase, but on the way I got an unfamiliar behavior.

I'm using the VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile method from the VideoThumbnail package.
This method is an asynchronous method that returns Future , but sometimes it fails to create a thumbnail and an error appears, so I'm trying to write exception handling.

In the above code, uint8list is grayed out and the message "Variables are not used" appears, but I think that it is clearly used even considering the scope.

I think it's possible to access variables in the outer scope from inside the try block {},
in Dart lang.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> In the above code, uint8list is grayed out and the message "Variables are not used" appears, but I think that it is clearly used even considering the scope.

You are misinterpreting the warning. The **value** isn't used. You are assigning values to it. But you never care and never *read* those values. So it's pointless to have this variable.

The warning will vanish, once you actually use the variable and read what you assigned to it.